# Question put on hold as primarily opinion-based

Tags: discussion

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44322015/unable-to-decide-on-an-appropriate-design-pattern) on SO which has been put on hold recently. While the nature of the question may invite opinion-based answers, it could still be helpful to me since i've hit a wall in trying to find a solution to my problem. In short, i would be in a better place than i'm in now if i got an answer.

By flagging it and closing this, it doesn't help me at all and others who might have similar questions. Answers, no matter how opinion-based, is still better than nothing to the person who's looking for some direction.

If the nature of question is not welcomed by SO, where does one go to gain such knowledge?

Comment: "it could still be helpful to me" - just to note: the nature of on-topic question on the network is that they do not only benefit you, they need to benefit others as well and need to be relatively easy to search for. Just a little heads up for future questions which are oriented around you getting helped rather than you offering a valuable question to the collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suraj below correctly states that https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ seems to be the most correct place to go, as this doesn't seem to require any code, and will get you the correct answer. They say on topic is

```
software development methods and practices
requirements, architecture, and design
quality assurance and testing
configuration, build, and release management
```

This seems to be a good fit with your original question.

If you have any WORKING code that you wished to review, then https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be better, but as has been stated below, you MUST have working code to get a good response from this site (thanks to Martijn Pieters for that).

Comment: And in direct answer to your question, yes and no. It might well make your question better, but it will still be opinion-based. The code will make it more appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ , but without code https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/  is better I think